# How to redirect ports for on a virtual interface?

Tags: linux, iptables, redirect, nat, port

There are two IPs associated with one physical network interface eth0 and eth0:0.

The following works fine for the first interface:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Howerver the same doesn't work for the second interface:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0:0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Also tried:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -d $THE_IP -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

So the question is how to do redirecting on a virtual interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.  Alias interfaces are a notational convention that don't actually exist at the deep layers of the kernel where iptables roams.  Use an IP address (your third example command is broken and will have produced an error message which should have clued you in) and all will be well.

Comment: edited the 3rd command to the one I've used and there is no error and redirection still doesn't work. Could you also elaborate on why nating based on the incoming interface is dangerous?

Comment: If that third command doesn't work, something else is wrong, because I use the exact same command and it works for me.  Time to break out the TRACE target and see what you can see.

Comment: Well, TRACE target? could you be more specific?

Comment: I could.  Can you read a manpage?

Comment: omg, this is rtfm all over the place.. :(

Comment: "Give a man a fish" and all that... If you want an answer to a different question (say, perhaps, "how do I diagnose why an iptables rule isn't working as I would expect?"), please ask it as a separate question.  And yes, we do expect you to expend *some* effort in solving your own problems.

Comment: You did answer the question: "Alias interfaces are a notational convention that don't actually exist at the deep layers of the kernel" well done. Tick for that. However, the rest of the story is not helpful but rather rude. Okay, I'll do my homework on TRACE, but being vague on security and not pointing out the obvious mistakes in the question is just as bad as me being lazy with the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Your third command is missing something : the enabling of multiport
Add `-m multiport`at the begining so it will be ok.
+ it is suposed to be `--dports` and `--to-ports`(plural form) even if you specify only a single port

Note that I had a similar problem + I already had an application using port 80 (apache2) that I had to kill before being able to use the redirection

Answer (score 0):

You should use TUN/TAP interface for doing this work. Refer to this [tutorial](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) for further details.